# How to redirect Filters in ASP.NET CORE 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an attribute class that extends IAsyncActionFilter in ASP.NET CORE 3.1 (C#).  Inside the OnActionExecutionAsync method, I would like to redirect to another controller/method WITHOUT calling any other filters that are on the initial method call.

I have tried using this inside OnActionExecutionAsync :

```
context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("MethodName", "Home", null);
await next();
```

I get the following error when I do that:

> If an IAsyncActionFilter provides a result value by setting the Result
>   property of ActionExecutingContext to a non-null value, then it cannot
>   call the next filter by invoking ActionExecutionDelegate.

I can remove the await next(), but then other filters on the initial method being called get called.

I have searched Google extensively, but come up short.

What is the proper syntax to achieve this goal?

Thanks!

Comment: _I can remove the await next(), but then other filters on the initial method being called get called._ I failed to reproduce the issue .Could you share a demo so that we can review and debug the code?  Did you try the IActionFilter interface ?

Comment: @XueliChen how do I attach the demo?  I am using IAsyncActionFilter.  The regular version does NOT meet mu needs.

Comment: You could add the relevant code that can reproduce the issue in your question, or share a demo link which is the url you posted in onedrive or github?Refer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61071/adding-links-to-comments

Comment: @DanGifford: Are you _certain_ the remaining filters are being called? It was my understanding that once the `ActionExeutingContext.Result` is set then the rest of the filter pipeline would stop executing. See [Cancellation and Short-Circuiting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cancellation-and-short-circuiting) in the [Filters in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cancellation-and-short-circuiting) documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I faced with the same problem and since no one answered, I just share my solution.

Just don't call next() if you set Result:

```
context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("MethodName", "Home", null);
if (context.Result != null)
    await next();
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if (context.Result == null)` ?

Comment: I think I mean: Just don't call next() if you "have" Result
Thanks for the notice.